# Android MediaPlayer Singleton

Tags: android, singleton, onclick, android-mediaplayer

I have read several of the articles on here that suggest using the singleton code, Which I have read and placed into the soundboard as I want to use the singleton code to only allow one mediaplayer instance no matter how many clicks the user defines.

Basically I only want one sound and if the user clicks another button during playback it stops the current sound and plays the one that is pressed.  I want only the one MediaPlayer instance but do not understand how to implement it.

Here is the basic idea of my code:

```
    package com.example.context;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;




    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.view.ContextMenu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    MediaPlayer player;

    int[] ressound ={R.raw.boomstick, R.raw.chainsaw, R.raw.shebitch, R.raw.byebye,
    R.raw.comegetsome, R.raw.groovy, R.raw.shoelace, R.raw.smart,   R.raw.yeahbaby};//added as needed
    int j=0;
    private static final String TAG = "MyTag";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


     //Coding for all buttons, registers, and Listeners
        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        registerForContextMenu(btn1); 
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        registerForContextMenu(btn2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        registerForContextMenu(btn3);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

     //On click Handlers for multiple buttons 
        public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn1:
        // action to perform on button 1
        j = 0;
        playResource();
        break;
    case R.id.btn2:
        // action to perform on button 1
        j = 1;
        playResource();
        break;
    case R.id.btn3:
        // action to perform on button 1    
        j = 2;
        playResource();
        break;

    }
         public void playResource(int j, int resource) {
    this.j = j;
    if (player != null) {
        if (player.isPlaying())
            player.stop();
        player.reset();
        //from MediaPlayer implementation (link above)
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(resource);
            if (afd == null) return;
            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
            afd.close();
            player.prepare();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create failed:", ex);
            // failed: return
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create failed:", ex);
            // failed: return
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create failed:", ex);
            // failed: return
        }
    }
    else {
        //player is null
        //it will create new MediaPlayer instance, setDataSource and call prepare
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, resource);
    }
    //if everything ok play file
    //in case of any error return from method before (catch)
    player.start();
}
```

This is what I had to update and change my code too but it is giving me a problem with passing the playresource() function.  Am I passing it wrong, should it be private that is passing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a Singleton for that. What are you doing is calling create method every time you want to play a file. That's wrong because you already have MediaPlayer instance.
Check [MediaPlayer.create implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/media/MediaPlayer.java#MediaPlayer.create%28android.content.Context,int%29).
I would do like that:

- create new method playResource(int j, int resource)
- in every case R.id.btnX i would call method playResource(X, R.raw.Y) - X and Y depends on btn

playResource method example:

```
private static final String TAG = "MyTag";
playResource(int j, int resource) {
    this.j = j;
    if (player != null) {
        if (player.isPlaying())
            player.stop();
        player.reset();
        //from MediaPlayer implementation (link above)
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(resource);
            if (afd == null) return null;
            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
            afd.close();
            player.prepare();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create failed:", ex);
            // failed: return
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create failed:", ex);
            // failed: return
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create failed:", ex);
            // failed: return
        }
    }
    else {
        //player is null
        //it will create new MediaPlayer instance, setDataSource and call prepare
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, resource);
    }
    //if everything ok play file
    //in case of any error return from method before (catch)
    player.start();
}
```

When you don't need MediaPlayer again, you should release it. For example in onPause() call:

```
if (player != null) {
    player.release();
    player = null;
}
```

I didn't test that so there could be errors. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am trying your code most of it has compiled just fine, It is throwing some errors. with the TAG, it doesn't recognize it.  Also with player.play it says its not an allowed, it needs to cast () with it.  and the final error that I cant get is context on context.getresources.open... is having issues with context.  Wants me to Capitalize it, but then throws more errors upon importing Context.  i have it fine by the link you gave as changing playresource(Context context, int j, int resource)

Comment: for clarity the only two errors that no longer throw exceptions is that openRawResources is int, and is not applicable for arguments int[].  And casting player.play()

Comment: Sorry, I had made some errors in code. Missing TAG is just a static String constant. There were also problem with code copied from Android source (player not mp and resource not resid and removed context before getResources()). MediaPlayer doesn't have play() method, it should be start(). I have updated code.

Comment: I updated my code and changed the function to playresources(j, ressound) and it works pretty good.  Problem is now if you press more than a couple of buttons it locks up the phone completely lol.  Is there a way around that or do you just have to hope the user isn't fingerdancing like a idiot.

Comment: Resetting player, getting fd and preparing player again takes some time. You have more possible solutions. You could ignore button presses if player is playing sound. Another simple solution is to disable buttons until playback stops. Then you have more complicated solutions. You could prepare player in another thread (try prepareAsync()) and when player is not prepared you ignore other button presses or use only the last pressed button. What you need and how would you implement that depends on what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The getSingletonObject() method should return an instance of MediaPlayer, created using the default constructor for MediaPlayer (without specifying the resource).

You could call getSingletonObject() from onCreate() in the main class and initialize the player with it.

Later in the onClick(), you should call, player.prepare() and then player.setDataSource(), passing in the resource.

So, your code should look something like the below:

```
   public static MediaPlayer getSingletonObject()
  {
    if (ref == null)
        // it's ok, we can call this constructor
        ref = new MediaPlayer();        
    return ref;
  }
```

In the main class, in the onCreate() method,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//....
//....
player=SingletonObject.getSingletonObject();
}
```

Hope you can figure out the code in onClick() by yourself. And don't forget to add the appropriate try..catch clauses in the onClick() method.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: by changing player to singletonobject how do i reference that, like its a function call or do i call to the ref of singleton? I am not for sure to to call back to this.

Comment: case R.id.btn9:
// action to perform on button 1 
j = 8;
getSingletonObject();
try {
player.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yeahbaby);
player.start();break;
     }
    }//closes onClick
    public MediaPlayer getSingletonObject()
    {     
           if (this.player == null)
               // it's ok, we can call this constructor
          player = new MediaPlayer();        
      return player;
    }

Comment: thats what I changed it too, it compiles and runs but if you press more than 1 button it still plays more than one sound.  And if you press three or more it crashes.

Comment: You should not do MediaPlayer.create() in the main class at all. You will get the MediaPlayer instance from the getSingletonObject() method in the onCreate() of the main class. You'll keep reusing the player instance instead of creating it again. Moreover, you should call player.stop() when playback has started and you click another button. Once the player has gone to the STOPPED state, you should again call player.prepare(), set the data source and then call player.start(). Hope this makes sense. If not, I'd be happy to post a code snippet.

Comment: Please do it kinda makes sense, but EVERY time I have used player.stop I receive a force close on my app.

Comment: on second thoughts, you need not make use of the singleton pattern at all here... the answer by @zoki, is self-explanatory.. that seems to be the best approach.. can you explain the error you're facing when you implement his method?

Comment: Thank you for trying at least I have a better Idea how the singleton pattern is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to solve this issue for a project of myself. I ran in the same issue that while playing a second playback will let the app crash.

Adding `player = new MediaPlayer();` solved the issue (seems no mediaplayer was initiated in the try-catch block).

See the code below:

```
    playResource(int j, int resource) {
this.j = j;
if (player != null) {
    if (player.isPlaying())
        player.stop();
    player.reset();

    try {
        player = new MediaPlayer(); //added to the code
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(resource);
        if (afd == null) return null;
        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        afd.close();
        player.prepare();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create failed:", ex);
        // failed: return
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create failed:", ex);
        // failed: return
    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create failed:", ex);
        // failed: return
    }
}
else {
    //player is null
    //it will create new MediaPlayer instance, setDataSource and call prepare
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, resource);
}
```